# How to get the NgControl in a structural directive applied to an Angular input Element?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Consider the input element

`<input type='text' customAttributeDirective='sampleIP' [formControl]='sampleControl'>`

For the attribute directive `customAttributeDirective`, NgControl can be obtained directly via dependency injection inside the constructor, or by injecting the injector and calling `injector.get(NgControl)` inside the constructor.

In case of a structural directive `customStructuralDirective` and markup,

`<input type='text' *customStructuralDirective='sampleIP1' [formControl]='sampleControl1'>`

dependency injection cannot get hold of `NgControl` associated with the input. The injector itself is different from attribute directive (verified by logging and checking the properties). Is it possible to get hold of the NgControl of the host element inside the structural directive's class?

Comment: Structural directives are just syntactic sugar. Decompose it into the template and the issue is clear: your directive lives on the ng-template and the input is now a child component.